# AWS QuickSight namespace creating problem

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried to create AWS QuickSight, but it still in the "CREATING" status more than 12hours.
I also tried to delete, but it doesn't work.
How can I resolve this?
Thank you for your time.

```
$ aws quicksight describe-namespace --aws-account-id __ACCNT_ID__ --namespace default
{
    "Status": 200,
    "Namespace": {
        "Name": "default",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:__ACCNT_ID__:namespace/default",
        "CapacityRegion": "us-east-1",
        "CreationStatus": "CREATING",
        "IdentityStore": "QUICKSIGHT"
    },
    "RequestId": "__REQUEST_ID__"
}
```

```
$ aws quicksight delete-namespace --aws-account-id __ACCNT_ID__ --namespace default

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DeleteNamespace operation: Namespace default of account __ACCNT_ID__has not completed signup. AWS account ID: __ACCNT_ID__, Namespace: default.
```

Creating AWS QuickSight followed by the lab below.

https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/cost/200_labs/200_cloud_intelligence/cost-usage-report-dashboards/dashboards/deploy_dashboards/